# Facebook Graph API (Post with Photo Ids) - (#10) Application does not have permission for this action

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish a post on my wall with two photos as attachments using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

**Here's what i did:**

1. I have selected all permissions in my user access token, and am using v2.5.
2. I have previously uploaded a photo to the endpoint: /me/photo and in response i got its id. i.e. "10154656374686756". This id will remain active for the next 24 hours.
3. Then I'm passing the photo id as a parameter (that i got in step 2) to my post using endpoint: /me/feed like this:
   [Graph API Explorer - Post Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro019.png)

But in response i'm getting the following error instead of the newly created post id:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "BzOCZ1z3tUH"
  }
}
```

I can't figure what i'm doing wrong here. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed#publish does not mention a parameter called `attached_media`

Comment: the way is instead mentioned here (Please see Publishing a multi-photo story): [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads)

Comment: Just came to know about an open bug report for this. [https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/301152166901519/?hc_location=ufi](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/301152166901519/?hc_location=ufi)